# How to get a index for a key I know to be unique in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of items in a particular order so I've decided to store them in an array

```
$items = array(
   "apple",
   "banana",
   "pear"
);
```

If the program is called with the parameter "banana" I need to be able to say "apple" comes before and "pear" comes after. Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
foreach($items as $k=>$v) { if ($v == "banana") { $current_key = $k }
```

So now I know that $current_key -1 is previous and +1 is next. It works, it just FEELS ugly to iterate over the entire array. Is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**
In case anyone cares, I decided to do a few quick tests to see how fast the ways of getting the information were. Over 1000 iterations, on an array of 6000 items, microtime retunred:

My Posted Way:  4.567 
Array_Search:  2.749

While I was thinking I also tried an approach that stored the data in a array of arrays like:

```
$items['banana']['next'] = 'pear';
$items['banana']['prev'] = 'apple';
```

which was, of course, the winner by miles ( 0.0005 ). None of this is really relevant, I was just curious and thought to share with anyone who reads this.

Comment: Sorry, but I do feel the need to nitpick your terminology: "apple", "banana" and "pear" are not keys in your example, they are values. They would be keys in the following example: array("apple" => "round", "banana" => "long", "pear" => "oblong"). 
What you call $current_key would be better described as a cursor or an index.

Comment: Yes, and im using the VALUE to find the KEY in the example ... you'll notice the value of $current_key is set to the array index, not the value. The title, however, is wrong, as I'm getting an index for a value i know to be unique :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_search()](https://www.php.net/array_search) should save you the loop.

Comment: In addition, `array_keys()` may be of use if you need more than just the first one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: The question says it's definitely unique, but neat. I never knew that array_keys took a second parameter.

Comment: Works like I charm. I even did some quick microtime() tests and it runs about twice as fast on a small array. No idea how it would fare on a large one. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `array_search` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php.

```
$key = array_search('banana', $items);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
$current_key=array_search('banana',$items);
```